# Function to restart python console

Tags: python, elpy

I wrote a very simple function to properly restart ipython console with elpy when evaluating the buffer or region:

```
(defun my-restart-python-console ()
  "Restart python console before evaluate buffer or region to avoid various uncanny conflicts, like not reloding modules even when they are changed"
  (interactive)
  (kill-process "Python")
  (kill-buffer "*Python*")
  (elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer))
```

Itt works but always ask confirmation, because "*Python*" has a running process, however I kill the process before killing the buffer.

The fun part:
If I evaluate the function body line by line it works...

Comment: Well, this function is very useful. When I edit two or more python buffers then I need restart the python interpreter. Do you want to open an issue on elpy's repository?
Sorry for write here, I can't write comments yet. I set my key binding <code>(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C-c") 'my-restart-python-console)</code>

Comment: @cactus good idea I will even write a commit, alter I make the code a bit elegant. Namely it should wait until the process is properly killed. Now I have some very intensive work but it will be on my TODO list. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I figured it out:
kill-process kills the process as a side effect, so it returns before that is really killed. So a function like this works:

```
(defun my-restart-python-console ()
  "Restart python console before evaluate buffer or region to avoid various uncanny conflicts, like not reloding modules even when they are changed"
  (interactive)
  (kill-process "Python")
  (sleep-for 0.05)
  (kill-buffer "*Python*")
  (elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `ipython`, why not just use the baked-in [`%reset`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-reset) magic command? You can also use:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload
```

To automatically reload imported modules on change.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your Emacs configuration file:

```
(defun my-restart-python-console ()
  "Restart python console before evaluate buffer or region to avoid various uncanny conflicts, like not reloding modules even when they are changed"
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer "*Python*")
      (let ((kill-buffer-query-functions nil)) (kill-buffer "*Python*")))
  (elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C-c") 'my-restart-python-console)
```

restart your Emacs run your code using `C-c C-x C-c`

In short, this code has the "if clause" for checking if *Python* buffer is open. This will help to be able to run `C-c C-x C-c` at any time of development even when there is no Python process already open. Another part is `kill-buffer-query-functions` which neglects the prompt for killing the *Python* buffer. In the original answer `sleep-for` is used which is not always functioning as expected and the provided code is more robust in some senses.

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE and thanx for your answer!  It would be even more usefull if you add a short explanation of what the code is doing, especially how it differs from the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks and you're absolutely welcome, I hope it helps. I have added a brief explanation.

Comment: If you let bind `kill-buffer-query-functions` like `(let ((kill-buffer-query-functions nil))
  (kill-buffer "*Python*"))` you avoid the side effect of changing the value for any code running afterwards.

Comment: @clemera Thanks! I have updated the function as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

From `kill-buffer` function documentation:

> The functions in `kill-buffer-query-functions` are called with the
>   buffer to be killed as the current buffer.  If any of them returns nil,
>   the buffer is not killed.

From `kill-buffer-query-functions` documentation:

> `kill-buffer-query-functions` is a variable defined in C source code.
>   Its value is (`process-kill-buffer-query-function`)

And `process-kill-buffer-query-function`:

> Ask before killing a buffer that has a running process.

So to kill buffer that has a running process you can disable kill buffer query functions like this:

```el
(let ((kill-buffer-query-functions nil))
  (kill-buffer "*Python*"))
```